# RewriteRule working both online and on a local subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a problem and i'm sure there is much solutions here but can't find what to search to find it...

I'm working on a website, and sometime i prefer to work on a local version.
Assuming this :

```
http://www.normal-website.com
http://127.0.0.1/local-version/
```

For each version i have a different rule to rewrite `css/style.css` to `css/style.css.php`  (my htaccess is in the root folder) :

```
RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9-/]+).css$ css/$1.css.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9-/]+).css$ local-version/css/$1.css.php [QSA,L]
```

How ca i write have only one rule, so i can have the same htaccess online and locally ? Also is it possible for any dir (like if i work on another version 127.0.0.1/website2/ for example) ?

Thanks a lot for your help, sorry for repost if you can find an existing answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9/-]+)\.css$ %{ENV:BASE}css/$1.css.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: +1, This is an amazing piece of mod-rewrite for me to study! I love how in the RewriteCond you are referring to the rules' Group captures that will be captured later in the rules. It's really rich, not understanding it yet. :)

Comment: to be honest i don't really understand how it works... but it works perfectly ! Thanks a lot for your help it can be very usefull when you move a website or use multiple sites based on same .htaccess. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81 and You're most welcome Pierre. This is the regex trick to capture value of current `RewriteBase` using back-references.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea with a smidgen of `if-then-else` logic:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} local-version
RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9-/]+).css$ local-version/css/$1.css.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9-/]+).css$ css/$1.css.php [QSA,L]
```

Try that on both htaccess files and let us know if there are any bugs.

If you have a second website, and your local folder is local-web2, insert a condition+rule pair before the final line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} local-version
RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9-/]+).css$ local-version/css/$1.css.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} local-web2
RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9-/]+).css$ local-web2/css/$1.css.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^css/([a-z0-9-/]+).css$ css/$1.css.php [QSA,L]
```

Remember: one condition (or multiple conditions), one rule. So the last line executes only if the other conditions have failed. So save it for the end.